# Android: keeping variables similar to a database

Tags: android

I have an android app that has a database of *People*. When I close the application, the data base remains and when I turn off the phone and turn it back on, the *People* are all there on my list.

My app supports other features such as letting the user decide the *Person* should be displayed. Eg, FirstName then LastName or vice versa etc. When I set these settings then quit the app and start it again. The settings are lost.

How do I keep these variables set? Kind of like they are in the database. What is the easiet/best way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

> Interface for accessing and modifying preference data returned by
>   getSharedPreferences(String, int). For any particular set of
>   preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients
>   share. Modifications to the preferences must go through an
>   SharedPreferences.Editor object to ensure the preference values remain
>   in a consistent state and control when they are committed to storage.
>   Objects that are returned from the various get methods must be treated
>   as immutable by the application.

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is small, you can use `SharedPreferences`. Or if your dataset is huge, you should use `SQLiteDatabase`.

```
getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("my_display_toggle", myDisplayToggle).commit(); 
Loading the value: getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("my_display_toggle", "default_value");
```

Comment: Can you give me an exmaple of using shared preferences for storing and getting a public static variable called myDisplayToggle?

Comment: Saving the value: `getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("my_display_toggle", myDisplayToggle).commit();` Loading the value: `getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("my_display_toggle", "default_value");`